# Running Gulp tasks in sequence does not seem to work

Tags: gulp

I am pretty new to Gulp and I kind of love it but also kind of don't really understand it at all so I might be going about this the wrong way entirely.

I have a file structure like this:

```
main
|-build
  |-big_file1.txt
  |-big_file2.txt
  |-small_file3.txt
  |-med_file4.txt
```

I want to copy the contents of `build` to a new dir and then delete some files so I set up two tasks like this:

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var foreach = require("gulp-foreach");
var del =require("del");

gulp.task("taskA", function(cb){
    var err = undefined;
    gulp.src("./build/*file*")
        .pipe(foreach(function(stream, file){
            stream.pipe(gulp.dest("./test"));
            return stream;
        }));

    cb(err);
});

gulp.task("taskB", ["taskA"], function(cb){
    var err = undefined;
    del(["./test/*big*"]);
    cb(err);
});
```

When I manually run `gulp taskA` the duplicate files appear in `./test` as expected and if I then run `gulp taskB` the ones prefixed with `big` are deleted. All groovy and as expected.

I then try to run the tasks in sequence like this:

```
gulp.task("both", ["taskA", "taskB"]);

gulp.task("taskA", function(cb){
    var err = undefined;
    gulp.src("./build/*file*")
        .pipe(foreach(function(stream, file){
            stream.pipe(gulp.dest("./test"));
            return stream;
        }));

    cb(err);
});

gulp.task("taskB", ["taskA"], function(cb){
    var err = undefined;
    del(["./test/*big*"]);
    cb(err);
});
```

And it doesn't work the same way. The log says that `taskA` is started then finished THEN `taskB` THEN `both` and the duplicate files are created in `./test` but the deletion never occurs. Can anyone explain what is happening here and suggest a way to fix it?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Making the tasks sequential

Well, based on the description you give, you should just return your streams to tell gulp when your tasks finished:

```
gulp.task("taskA", function (){
    return gulp.src("./build/*file*")
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./test"));
});

gulp.task("taskB", ["taskA"], function (){
    return del(["./test/*big*"]);
});
```

It is *possible* to use callbacks but you need to call them in the right place. In the code in your question you call them *before* the operations to be performed by `gulp.src().pipe...` have had a chance to run. They are asynchronous.

#### Simplifying the Gulpfile

I've explained how to fix your code so that the sequencing would work but you could combine the two tasks into one with;

```
gulp.task("single", function (){
    return gulp.src(["./build/*file*", "!./build/*big*"])
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./test"));
});
```

Given the input you've shown, this will give you the same result as running the task `both`. It copies the files that match `./build/*file*` but **not** `./build/*big*` because of the exclamation point at the beginning of the 2nd pattern. This has the advantage of not doing needless copying only to delete extraneous files afterwards.

Comment: That makes sense and does fix the issue as I described. However, my example was an attempt to simplify a much more complex set of tasks which it does not seem to help. I can only guess that there is more than one problem with my gulpfile :( Not wanting to be that guy who posts an entire build on stack overflow and asks if 'anyone can fix it' I will accept your answer and see if I can work out what question I need to actually ask. Thanks for the info though it is helpful as I didn't know about using the `!` when matching files

Comment: @popClingwrap Your plan is exactly what we want users of SO to do. When someone posts a problem that is solvable and the problem is solved but it does not solve a larger problem they have, it is not good if they start editing the question to add more and more stuff. We call those questions ["chameleon questions"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions). By all means, if a problem remains, once you've tried fixing it on your own and got a [mcve], and you know it is not a duplicate, you should post it.